# Connection string for azure failover groups

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have set up a failover group and have tried to connect using SSMS to <my-failover-group-name>.database.windows.net as the server URL but it times out and does not let me connect.

In each of the sql servers I have allowed my IP address through the firewall. As I understand what they are saying here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview I should be able to use the above as my connection string. I can connect to each of the individual servers in the failover group no problem.

I have also tried connecting to tcp:<my-failover-group-name>.database.windows.net,1433 using the same credentials as I use for the servers in the cluster and I get login failed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just ran into the same thing.  In SQL Management Studio you need to specify the database name under Options >> Connect to database.

Comment: Still asking me to provide server instance.

Answer (score 0):

Note the failover involves updating the DNS record so the client connections are redirected to the new primary only after the client DNS cache is refreshed. For more information, click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview).

Comment: I've flushed DNS, the failover group connection still doesn't work